# Developing in xcode 6, i want it to scale in iPhone 6 devices

Tags: ios, xcode6, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

i've created a new app in Xcode 6, the size in the storyboard simulates 4 inch screen.

I want that on iPhone 6/6+ devices it will scale up, and not adjust.
I tried to remove the Launch Screen file, it is now scaled, but now i get 2 black stripes in the upper and bottom of the screen.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: You need the 4" launch images.

Comment: You need to use "Size Classes" in order to adjust to multiple screen size. Then use AutoLayout constraints to organize your screens.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH1-SW1

Comment: Question - why? Why would you cripple your app so it doesn't support the latest iPhones? Please don't do this. Think of your users. People want apps that take advantage of the bigger screens.

Comment: the app is for 3 users, adjusting it takes too much time for this